# Executing windows batch script on Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

I am building a project using Maven and using Jenkins for continuos integration. After the maven build i am getting an executable jar in my target folder which i am trying to run using a windows batch command as build step. But when i put the command in the box under execute windows batch command i get the following error

> "cmd /c call /tmp/hudson2033384960131825453.bat FATAL: command
>   execution failed java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in
>   directory "/hosting/workspace/myProject"): error=2, No such file or
>   directory""

I am using mac OSX 10.9.3. The jenkins is deployed in a remote server which i don't have access to.

I want to execute this jar file as a build process. How can i do it?

Comment: can you post your command + windows doesn't have this directory structure generally `/hosting/workspace/myProject`

Comment: runs jenkins on windows?

Comment: @JigarJoshi   java -jar target/myProject.jar. This is the windows batch command i put in the Execute Windows Command in jenkins

Comment: where do you specify this directory `/hosting/workspace/myProject` in your jenkins plan configuration

Comment: My machine which is the client is mac ..i am not using windows..

Comment: are you trying to execute windows batch script on your mac ?

Comment: whatever the OS i am using , i think jenkins can execute the batch file right? It doesn't matter whether i use mac or windows. The script is getting executed in the Jenkins environment in a remote server

Comment: I am executing the bat command in jenkins server...not in my machine..there is an Execute Windows Batch Command option in jenkins. Instead of executing in shell i am trying to execute as a windows batch command

Comment: jenkins can execute batch script **depending on OS it is running on**, you can't ask jenkins running on linux to launch some windows specific commands

Comment: where was this upvote coming from and why... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be expecting a windows batch command to be able to run on a mac. Jenkins is pretty cool, I agree, but it isn't magical.

Also, yes, it is a little confusing that the option is available to you even though you are on a Mac, but its there incase you have a linux / mac master with windows slave: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17010?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab

You cannot execute a windows batch command on mac or linux, end of story.

Comment: I agree to what you have said. But doesn't Jenkins have an option to build in a windows environment independent of OS it is running on?

Comment: Nope, hence the need for a distributed architecture : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to launch windows command through jenkins on another operating system which is not going to work